# Não é possível multiplicar a sequência por um não-int do tipo 'float', mesmo quando transformado em 'map'

Tags: python, float, map

nível: iniciante

Eu preciso multiplicar isso `[list] * [float]`:

```
eta = [random.random () - 0,5] * eps
```

mas quando tento fazer um `float` ou um `map`, ele ainda não funciona (por causa de tipos de operandos não suportados). existe outra maneira de fazer isso? obrigado.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no site em inglês do StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Python's default multiplication of a sequence is "concatenate the sequence with itself N times" - and is therefore defined only for sequences X integers.

Apparantly you intend to have each member of the sequence multiplied in place, and may have overheard someone telling you to use `map`.

`map` is a built-in to perform one operation on each member of a sequence, and it would work like this:

```
new_list = list(map(lambda element: element * float_value, original_list))
```

Python has a short syntax for that in the form of list comprehensions, where one can put an expression directly, instead of passing a function as a parameter to `map`:

```
new_list = [element * float_value for element in original_list]
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em português. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no site em inglês do StackOverflow

Comment: it happens: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'

Comment: e o que deu errado quando você usa como eu mostrei acima, em vez de `new_list = orignal_list * value`?